# Why is Outlook conditional content showing in Apple mail?

Tags: outlook, html-email, conditional-comments

I'm wrestling with an HTML email design destined primarily for Outlook/Office 365. Following advice on various sites I'm wrapping my content table in conditional comments in order to give it a fixed width (no max-width support in Outlook). However, content inside those conditional comments is also showing up in Apple Mail (desktop and mobile versions). Can anyone tell me why?

Here's the conditional code I'm using:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="600">This should ONLY show up in Outlook
<![endif]-->
<table bgcolor="#bbbbbb" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:700px; border:1px solid blue">
    <tr>
        <td>
            CONTENT FOR ALL EMAIL CLIENTS
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
```

That text "This should ONLY show up in Outlook" is displaying in Mail. And I can see the red border of the surrounding (conditional) table in Mail as well. Why is this conditional failing to limit the scope of that code to Outlook?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show up in any Apple, AOL, Andoid, IOS, Yahoo, Gmail client I tested. It only shows up in Outlook. It does not show up for Outlook 365 or Outlook.com. Perhaps there is something in the code you didn't post.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe. Can I ask what you were sending *from* in your tests? I was sending from Outlook (PC)

Comment: I send from http://litmus.com to test different email clients and http://putsmail.com to test different devices. I use Adobe Campaign to send emails to clients. Half of our subscribers use Outlook, so testing in Outlook is very important to me.

Answer (score 1):

gwally's comment pointed me toward the answer. Since his testing didn't give him the same results I was getting, it suggested that something about my process was the problem. It wasn't the code, though; it was the fact that I was sending the email out via Outlook. If I sent the same code via Mailchimp it arrives exactly as expected.

I knew about Outlook's horrible (non-)support for pretty-much anything useful when it comes to HTML emails. However, I'd assumed that this applied when it *received* emails and that it would pass outgoing code along as-attached, and only interpret/murder it when it was received as an incoming mail. What I hadn't accounted for (or expected, though perhaps I should have if I'd thought it through in detail) was that Outlook apparently forces the same horrible rules onto the *outgoing* code, meaning that every other client basically suffered from the same crippling limitations as Outlook -- including seeing content that should have been Outlook-only. The code I had created wasn't bad, it's just that it was getting borked before it even got out the door. (That's a very simplistic description of the situation, I realise, and I'm sure there's a lot more nuance to precisely how Outlook parses outgoing HTML, but the result ends up being the same for me).

Since our organisation is almost entirely Outlook-based and these emails are designed as reusable templates for internal announcements (to be sent out via that client), I guess I'm just going to have to suck it up. But it's undeniably vexing.

Anyway, at least I now have a clearer understanding of where the goalposts lie.

Comment: Thanks for following this up! I had no idea that Outlook screws with markup upon _sending_ an outgoing bulk mail. Good to know.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bugger! Basically, if Outlook is handling the sending process then anything inside Outlook-only conditional comments gets baked into the code for ALL recipients. So you can kiss goodbye to responsive emails -- because you're stuck with a choice between everything being 100% width with no limit (Outlook doesn't support max-width) which will look dreadful in desktop clients, or fixed width, which inevitably looks a bit gimpy in mobile viewports. Maybe Outlook for Mac would avoid that (it uses webkit I think) but I can't find a way to get it to insert HTML like the PC version can.

Comment: @RickLecoat All of the drawbacks for email providers creeps up when you send or receive.

Comment: @RickLecoat In the future, if you're having issues, I suggest sending proofs to using something neutral like http://putsmail.com. It's a tool I use along with http://litmus.com for testing emails. I also use Outlook every single day, but I never consider sending from Outlook because of it's issues,

Comment: In general, I’d agree. Thing is, the emails in question will, once finished, *have* to be sent from Outlook (they’re templates for internal announcements, not one-off marketing newsletters, and get used several times a day). So, in this specific scenario, how well they work when sent via Mailchimp (whilst undeniably useful for checking quality of one’s code) is less important/relevant than how well they work when sent via Outlook. Annoying but true.